# iCarousel + UITableView = cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath always null

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, icarousel

I have a problem that is giving me a big head pain. When I call to:

```
(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`
```

I got always `indexPath=null` with the following error.

```
 Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[Categories copyWithZone:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xc386b20'
```

I have this code in my `GallerySpirituosenViewController.h`:

```
@interface GallerySpirituosenViewController :  UIViewController <iCarouselDataSource, iCarouselDelegate , UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource>
  @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView    *table_categories;
  @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView    *table_brands;
  @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView    *table_items;
  @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet iCarousel      *carousel;
  @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView         *filtersContainer;
@end
```

And later on in my `GallerySpirituosenViewController.m` I extend the "iCarrousel" which is working properly and I have one View with 3 `UITableView` inside it.

Here I can show how I call the `datasource` and `delegate` for one table:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.table_brands.dataSource = self;
    self.table_brands.delegate = self;

    _carousel.type      = iCarouselTypeCoverFlow2;
}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [super viewDidUnload];

    //free up memory by releasing subviews
    self.carousel = nil;
}
```

and later on this the code where I populate the table:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return [categories count];//arrays
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    //  NSInteger carouselIndex = [self.carousel indexOfItemViewOrSubview:tableView];
    //  PersonData *data = [items objectAtIndex:carouselIndex];
    static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"SimpleTableItem";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
    }

    cell.textLabel.text = [categories objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    return cell;
}
```

And here is the debug of the object categories:

[image]

And the indexPath with null value:

[image]

Also here the object Category.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface Categories : NSObject
    @property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *id;
    @property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *title;
    @property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *sys_language_uid;
@end
```

And Category.m

```
#import "Category.h"

@implementation Categories

@synthesize id,title,sys_language_uid;


- (void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)encoder {
    [encoder encodeObject:id forKey:@"id"];
    [encoder encodeObject:title forKey:@"title"];
    [encoder encodeObject:sys_language_uid forKey:@"sys_language_uid"];
}

- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)decoder {
    if (self = [super init]) {
        self.id = [decoder decodeObjectForKey:@"id"];
        self.title = [decoder decodeObjectForKey:@"title"];
        self.sys_language_uid = [decoder decodeObjectForKey:@"sys_language_uid"];
    }
    return self;
}


@end
```

Comment: Give us how to create categories variable and assign value to this? Is it an NSMutableArray which contains NSString?

Comment: Not so easy copy this code, because is coming from other site of the project, but Is a NSMutableArray with object inside. I read this MtableArray with this code:-(NSMutableArray *) load:   ( NSString * )  name {
    
    NSMutableArray * items = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithFile:[utils pathByName:name]];
    
    if ( items == nil ){
        items = [NSMutableArray new];
    }
    
    return items;
}

Comment: indexPath is not null. indexes property in indexPath instance is NULL. It does not seem to be a problem in my tableviews and i don't think your problem is here.

Comment: umm, thanks for your comment. Could you give a tip ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`[categories objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]` return Categories object.

You get string like this.

`cell.textLabel.text = [categories objectAtIndex:indexPath.row].id`

OR

`cell.textLabel.text = [categories objectAtIndex:indexPath.row].title`

Edit more:

You should declare `title variable` like this

`@property(nonatomic,strong) NSString*title;`

NOT

`@property(nonatomic,copy) NSString*title;`

Comment: Thanks for you help, that is the point I have no "copy" I have "retain" I also edited my post for give more info. Thanks again

Comment: Have you tried this : cell.textLabel.text = [categories objectAtIndex:indexPath.row].title

Comment: hahhah, GREAT!! merci, not exactly with that but it works with this code   Categories * category = [categories objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    
    cell.textLabel.text = category.title;

Answer (score 0):

You said:

> When I call to:
>
> ```
>   (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
>   cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`
> ```
>
> I got always
>   indexPath=null with the following error.

The method `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` is a tableview datasource method. 
You should not be calling that method yourself. The table view calls that method on your code.

Comment: Yes I mean, I not call this method for myself. I wanted say that is there where the code broke getting always this indexPath=null

Answer (score 0):

As I understand categories is an object and not a string. What is the objective of this line?

```
cell.textLabel.text = [categories objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```